# How to set CATALINA_HOME in log4j.xml?

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

I need something like this:

"param name="File" value="${CATALINA_HOME}/logs/log4j.log"

I saw a lot of similar questions, but there is no working solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. send the `CATALINA_HOME` as an environment variable using `-D` option.  You just have to run

`set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -DCATALINA_HOME=%CATALINA_HOME%` if you are on windows or
`export JAVA_OPTS=${JAVA_OPTS} -DCATALINA_HOME=$CATALINA_HOME` for unix.

Now just use ${CATALINA_HOME} into your log4j configuration file and this should work.

Comment: No. I did it first! But i have gotten an exception. I can't access from configuration file to system environment!

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd define another one, when it's already there. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10769833/839646).

Answer (score 15):

For Tomcat 6.0 or newer use `catalina.base` (rather than `catalina.home`):

`param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/log4j.log"`

Depending on the host system, the two may be different, for example:

```
catalina.home: /usr/share/tomcat7
catalina.base: /var/lib/tomcat7
```

Under `catalina.home` there's the `bin` folder.

Under `catalina.base` there are `conf`, `logs`, `webapps` and other folders/links.

Tomcat uses `catalina.base` itself to configure the logging directory - see `conf/logging.properties` where it says:

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
```

Comment: when i run my application using eclipse `${catalina.base}` gives me `D:\EclipseWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2`. and also log file not generated. any solutions?

Comment: Great. Works to me

Answer (score 10):

`param name="File" value="${catalina.home}/logs/log4j.log"`

The `catalina.home` property is already made available by Tomcat.

Find a (very) brief example on the [Tomcat 5.5 logging page](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/logging.html#log4j) and additional detail in the following SO question:

[Log4j, configuring a Web App to use a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216781/log4j-configuring-a-web-app-to-use-a-relative-path)