# Writing unit test with spring

Tags: java, spring, junit

I'm new in unit-testing and trying to intanciate `ApplicationContext` in a unit-test as follows:

```
ApplicationContext context;

@Before
public void init(){
    context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath://webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext-sheduler.xml");
}
```

But when I try to do so I get the exception:

```
2015-05-29 10:20:13,494 ERROR Unable to create file ${sys:catalina.home}/logs/partner-sheduler.log java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:306)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:290)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:71)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:60)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:79)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.createAppender(RollingFileAppender.java:182)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:133)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:744)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:683)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:675)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:349)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:150)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:364)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:422)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:269)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl$PrivateManager.getContext(LogFactoryImpl.java:108)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getLoggersMap(LogFactoryImpl.java:52)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:43)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:84)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:59)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:58)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.org.dst.tt.test.DailyProfitTest.init(DailyProfitTest.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

2015-05-29 10:20:13,497 ERROR catching java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:133)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:744)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:683)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:675)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:349)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:150)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:364)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:422)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:269)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl$PrivateManager.getContext(LogFactoryImpl.java:108)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getLoggersMap(LogFactoryImpl.java:52)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:43)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:84)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:59)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:58)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.org.dst.tt.test.DailyProfitTest.init(DailyProfitTest.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create a manager
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:73)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:60)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:79)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.createAppender(RollingFileAppender.java:182)
    ... 51 more

2015-05-29 10:20:13,500 ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile.
2015-05-29 10:20:13,526 ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
2015-05-29 10:20:13,534 ERROR Unable to locate appender R for logger
```

How to fix that?

The test doesn't contain anything except the `Before` method and an empty method annotatted with `@Test`.

Comment: Fix the log file name in lgo4j config. The first line of stack trace points towards it `Unable to create file ${sys:catalina.home}/logs/partner-sheduler.log java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`

Comment: `${sys:catalina.home}`  will not work in log4j config file as long as you do not set `catalina.home` environment var. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769667/how-to-set-catalina-home-in-log4j-xml) out

Comment: @FranMontero So I should pass catalina.home as a JVM option, right?

Comment: @St.Antario that should work ;)

Comment: @FranMontero Don't see how I can pass a JVM option when I'm running unit-tests under eclipse.

Comment: @St.Antario `right-click -> run configurations -> Junit (right click -> new) -> arguments` if you are running the test another way check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579776/how-to-set-jvm-parameters-for-junit-unit-tests question

Comment: @FranMontero That works perfectly. Thank you. But now I got another exception while running the unit-test. __COnfiguration file doesn't exist__

Comment: @St.Antario Great! I'm writing an answer, if you have a new error try to solve it yourself and if you can't post another question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use environment variables in `log4j.properties`configuration file, you have to pass the argument you need to the JVM when running the test.
YOu can achieve that with a run configutarion:

`right-click -> run configurations -> Junit (right click -> new) -> arguments`

if you are running the test another way check [How to set JVM parameters for Junit Unit Tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579776/how-to-set-jvm-parameters-for-junit-unit-tests)