# How to get the actual source path in Struts 2?

Tags: java, path, upload, struts2

I have a little problem with Struts 2 when I try to get the context path :

```
ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("\\WebContent\\resources\\img\\");
```

I got this path:

> C:\Users\killian\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SiteWebAdministrable\WebContent\resources\imgicone.jpg

Why the exact source path ?

Because i need to upload and save images for an admin website to control background and without the actual path i cannot save images in the resources path...
So i save the path with the name and extension in the database (no problem), and i need to save the image in the resource directory (image problem...)

Can someone help me please ? Did i forgot something ?

This question is the answer ?

[How do you get the project path in Struts 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239923/how-do-you-get-the-project-path-in-struts-2)

Comment: What is wrong with the path you've got?

Comment: I search a path like C:\Users\killian\workspace\SiteWebAdministrable\WebContent\resources\img\icone.jpg to save the image in the project directory

Answer (score 0):

```
servletContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/resources/img/name_of_image.png")
```

So, passing the "/" to getRealPath() would return you the absolute disk file system path of the /web folder of the expanded WAR file of the project. Something like /path/to/server/work/folder/demo.war/ which you should be able to further use in File or FileInputStream.

Note that most starters don't seem to see/realize that you can actually pass the whole web content path to it and that they often use

```
String absolutePathToIndexJSP = servletContext.getRealPath("/") + "demo.png";
```

instead of

```
String absolutePathToIndexJSP = servletContext.getRealPath("/demo.png");
```

getRealPath() is unportable; you'd better never use it

**Use getRealPath() carefully.**

If all you actually need is to get an InputStream of the web resource, better use ServletContext#getResourceAsStream() instead, this will work regardless of the way how the WAR is expanded. So, if you for example want an InputStream of index.jsp, then do not do:

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(servletContext.getRealPath("/demo.png")); // Wrong!
```

But instead do:

```
InputStream input = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/demo.png"); // Right!
```

Or if you intend to obtain a list of all available web resource paths, use ServletContext#getResourcePaths() instead.

```
Set<String> resourcePaths = servletContext.getResourcePaths("/");
```

Answer (score 0):

I try `.\File` in eclipse struts debug mode, and get eclipse folder:

```
private String localDirectory = ".\\File";
File localFile = new File(localDirectory, FileName);
System.out.println(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
```