# Dynamically loading property values in property file

Tags: java, log4j

I am using log4j in my spring+struts+hibernate application.It is working perfectly but the only problem is the log file is stored in the specific path.Is there any way to change the path of the log file dynamically.I want the log file to be generating on the server path.

This is the property file am using for log4j

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
**log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\loging.log**
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=debug, file, stdout
```

I want to load the server path dynamically here**log4j.appender.file.File=server path**.

Any idea?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer

http://www.developer.com/java/ent/dynamically-configure-log4j-properties-in-a-clustered-environment.html

[Log4j, configuring a Web App to use a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216781/log4j-configuring-a-web-app-to-use-a-relative-path)

Answer (score 1):

you must change the l`og4j.properties file` like: `log4j.appender.appender_name.File = ${file.name}` and in the code when call `PropertyConfigurator.configure`, just do `System.setProperty("file.name","your path")`

[How to configure log4j with a properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288876/how-to-configure-log4j-with-a-properties-file)

Basically you need to write a custom logger class in which you call the above method.You can refer the above link.

Comment: could you tell me where can i set the PropertyConfigurator.configure in my application