# How to write file append property file in log4j

Tags: java, log4j

Here is my log4j property file I am using console appender but i need to use file appender could anybody expline me how to write that and where to find that file after run my application....

```
 # Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.base}/logs/mylog.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the standard properties file which I use for my project.. this will print logging output on console as well as in a file.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\springtest.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: thats created now but i don't want to specify the drive i want store in project itself how to do that thanks –  user2998826

Comment: See this stackoverflow question where its been explained in detail.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216781/log4j-configuring-a-web-app-to-use-a-relative-path

Comment: that is printing all server messages but not inside class messages...plz help me

Comment: Have you placed this in the class path ?? Does it shows some warning at the beginning of the stacktrace??

Comment: now that works fine but how create superate class file for all the class

Comment: What you can do is write a separate class which will have static methods for logging information, debug-info and errors. Methods will have some implementation like this Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class).info("ANY INFO",OBJECT); this way you can keep your logging separate in a different class.

Answer (score 0):

For appending to a file, follow the below properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\loging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Visit [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/) for more details

to place in tomcat directory:

```
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.base}/logs/mylog.log
```

Comment: weather i need to create that file in c folder or that will create automatically

Comment: @user2998826 it will be created automatically. Change the seperators accordingly. also try with c:/logging.log.

Comment: thats created now but i don't want to specify the drive i want store in project itself how to do that thanks

Comment: You can use something like ${catalina.base} or sometimes ${basedir}.. check this http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html for more details on that

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope that helps