# How to set the logfile name of Spring application and log to tomcat /logs folder?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

How can I set the logging path relative to tomcat dir `/logs/mylog.log`?

What I tried: changing the `logging.file` property in `application.properties`

leaving the filename out: `#logging.file=` -> everything is logged to console, thus written into `tomcat/logs/localhost.yyyy-mm-dd.log`

`logging.file=mylog.log` -> written to console, thus same as #logging.file

`logging.file=d:/mylog.log` -> written to the location d:/mylog.log

`logging.file=../logs/mylog.log` -> written to console, thus still to localhost*.log

None was successful.
I'm not interested in externalising the configuration eg by providing system or environment variables.

Comment: What fire are you editing ?

Comment: all spring properties are configured in `application.properties`

Comment: maybe I dont understand the question correctly but what about this: `logging.file=../logs/mylog.log`

Comment: @Patrick I now also tried this, but still gets logged to `localhost-*.log`.

Comment: I just created a simple boot app with one info logging in main and just the one property in prop file. Deployed on my local running tomcat. Result was the creation of the mylog.log in /logs. Maybe you have some stuff whats overrides?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just created a simple `Spring-boot`app from spring starter build as `war` file. I have just this modification in `@SpringBootApplication` class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LogApplication {

   private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LogApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Controller
    @ResponseBody
    public static class IndexController{

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String getindex(){
            logger.error("Error Logging");
            return "Hello";
        }
    }
}
```

And this property in `application.properties`:

```
logging.file=../logs/mylog.log
```

Build the application using maven `mvn clean install` and put the `war` file inside `webapps` folder of `tomcat`. Started tomcat using `startup.bat` and hit successful the endpoint `http://localhost:8080/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`.

And the log was written in `logs/mylog.log`:

[image]

```
2017-01-04 14:57:10.755 ERROR 8236 --- [http-apr-8080-exec-4] com.example.LogApplication               : Error Logging
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Then maybe it's the tomcat itself that has some strange configuration causing a different behavior for me. Will report back when I found it. Meanwhile I'll accecpt your answer, as you proved the solution.

Comment: I don't know why, but I have to use the following path: `logging.file=logs/mylog.log`, otherwise the "/log" path is created in the upper folder of tomcat home, outside the tomcat folder itself.

Comment: @membersound strange. You dont have any other logging configuration file like ` logback.xml` or something else in your application? Or maybe set the `logging.path` in properties file?

Comment: No I'm just relying on the default spring-boot configuration. tested on tomcat 7 + 8

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the environment variable for configuring the log path.

Tomcat sets a **catalina.home** system property which you can use

log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG,errorfile

log4j.appender.errorfile.File=**${catalina.home}**/logs/LogFilename.log

Note:-

This may not work On Debian (including Ubuntu), ${catalina.home} will not work because that points at /usr/share/tomcat6 which has no link to /var/log/tomcat6. Here just use ${catalina.base}. [Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216781/log4j-configuring-a-web-app-to-use-a-relative-path)

Comment: I cannot make use of environment variable, as I run several `war` files within the same tomcat webserver, and only want to change the logging for that specific app. an envrn var would have impact any all

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to second Tomz's response and point you to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html) because they show you how to switch over from logback to log4j which is probably easier for you.

I would strongly recommend not deploying Spring Boot in war files, but as executable fat jars. It makes things a lot easier when you can just type this to test a configuration and deploy it:

`java -jar my-service.jar /opt/my-service/conf/application.yml`

Comment: Well but in my case I have no choice and have to deploy a war. That's why I'm asking...