# java - log4j File appender location path

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am writing a program using log4j to log exceptions or error to a log file. This is how my `log4j.properties` look like:

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, FILE


# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.FILE.File=C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/Logging/log/test.log


# Set the immediate flush to true (default)
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

# Set the threshold to debug mode
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug


# Set the append to false, overwrite
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true


# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n
```

The code works fine but my concern is regarding the relative file path that it writes to. As you can see, I have hardcoded the file path and it wouldn't be convenient if I run this program on somebody's else PC as it will throw a `FileNotFoundException`

Is there a way I can standardize this relative file path to be read the log file in the same directory always so it will always be able to log into the file no matter where it is run??

Comment: You could use a parameter like **${logRoot}/log/test.log** from command line, maven pom or whatelse you use.

Comment: I am using Intellij IDE

Comment: Than I asume this will be standalone application. I've never used that IDE but there must be a place where you can define command line arguments for your program.

Comment: I mean i did tried the parameter you mentioned but it throws an FileNotFound exception, meaning it couldn't locate `${logRoot}`

Comment: What does the parameter represent?

Comment: You should supply something like **-DlogRoot=c:/bla-bla** to your arguments.

Comment: I still don't follow what it means

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev was talking about how you run your application - either via `java -jar yourJar.jar` you would have to add that run parameter `java -DlogRoot=c:/blabla -jar yourJar.jar`

Comment: you can set these parameters as well on any IDE (intellij Eclipse...) in the 'edit run configuration' tab

Comment: does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216781/log4j-configuring-a-web-app-to-use-a-relative-path